# Why is Wepoll's EPOLLONESHOT different from Epoll?

Tags: linux, windows, epoll

I noticed that in Linux's epoll, EPOLLONESHOT is 1u << 30, but in Wepoll's implementation, it's 1U << 31, why is that?